# I have “Server Error in '/' Application. Invalid postback or callback argument.” and i dont know how to fix it

Tags: c#, asp.net, compiler-errors, server-error

I have a WebForm page which contains a link to a User control. 
This user control has a grid view with a button. 
When I push the button it invokes a pop up dialogue (another user control) that requests user information.

When i click submit i get a server error 'invalid post back...'
I have other pages like this one, but they work perfectly fine.
do you have any idea what could be wrong?

note that may be helpful: the text boxes do contain validation, that don't let you pick a weight less than 0. or leave a field empty. could it be this?

thankyou for your help guys

```
 <asp:GridView  ID="GridView1" class="GridMain" AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowStyle-Wrap="true"  DataKeyNames="ID_MSG_SLIP, ID_ITEMPER_COLLECTIONORDER, ID_COLLECTIONORDER" runat="server">
    <Columns  >
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Confirm Collection" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="btnGreen" runat="server" Class="btnGreen" ImageUrl="~/img/green.png" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID_MSG_SLIP")+","+ Eval("ID_ITEMPER_COLLECTIONORDER")+","+ Eval("ID_COLLECTIONORDER")%>'/>
                <!--This is the pop up panel and trigger   -->
                <pop2:DatePopUp ID_MSG_SLIP='<%#Eval("ID_MSG_SLIP")%>'  ID_ITEMPER_COLLECTIONORDER='<%# Eval("ID_ITEMPER_COLLECTIONORDER")%>' ID_COLLECTIONORDER='<%# Eval("ID_COLLECTIONORDER")%>' runat="server" ID="DatePopUp" />
```

Comment: Seems your `CommandArgument` in `ImageButton` has invalid syntax, check accordingly. Also a friendly reminder - avoid posting your code as an image, instead copy & paste with code block marker in your question.

Comment: do not post images. Share your code. If the images get deleted, your question becomes worthless.

Comment: the issue is the 3rd user control. when i push submit it gives me a server post back error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    if(!isPostBack){
//Load your grid data inside this
}
```